# Change between two view controllers programmatically at the first launch

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

I have two view controllers. First is empty, second contains a text field. If this field is empty, I need to move to the second controller automatically.

I tried this:

```
NSUInteger VCcount = self.navigationController.viewControllers.count;
UIViewController *btVC = self.navigationController.viewControllers[VCcount-2];


if([self.btViewController.Text.text isEqualToString:@""])
{
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:btVC animated:YES];

}
```

and this:

```
UIViewController* btVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BTViewController"];
```

But at the first launch program knows only current controller and doesn't know about thesecond.

How can I get there?

Comment: Where do you call the instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier from? You should first instantiate the VC and then push it onto the stack.

Comment: Are you sure the if statement is correctly evaluated? I.e. the btViewController.Text object is not nil? I would rather compare the lenght of the text property (text.length == 0).

Comment: Yes, I am sure. I don't know how to call the second view controller

Answer (score 0):

See the example below:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    self.textField.text = @"some text";

    if (self.textField.text.length == 0) {
        UIViewController *secondVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"secondVC"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondVC animated:NO];
    }
}
```

If you comment out the assignment of "some text" to the textField, the secondVC will be instantiated and presented. I don't know what exactly you are trying to achieve with first two lines of your presented code.

If the secondVC already exist, you can just take a reference to it by knowing its index on the stack, or inspecting viewControllers array of your navigationController before you push it to the stack. If it does not exist, you just instantiate it from storyboard (with the correct identifier) and push it.

Comment: Still not working. I checked the ID. I can't see the second view from the first.

Comment: Can you share more code, in which methods are you calling the code presented exactly? Put breakpoint or NSLog right before pushing the btVC to check if the btVC is not nil. What is the lifecycle of this call - in which VC lifecycle methods do you call this?

Comment: I did it. Thanks for help. I didn't know about `viewDidAppear` and tried this code in `viewDidLoad`. Sorry)